# Easy way to List info from arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have the code below which checks the registry for entries (more than 20 of them) and if it doesn't exists it creates a registry key and adds it to an array. 
After that I need to check for all the names in the array to my other array and if it matches, I need it to pull the info from my second array and show it on the screen(the log location, registry location etc). But Can't really figure out how to match the array and write in on the screen without writing very long if statements.

Does anyone know a good way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

```
$Reg = "HKLM:\Software\"
$NeedtoCheck = @()
$testing = @("Test1Name","Test2Name", "Test3Name")
$allTests = @(
$Test1 = @{
Name = "Test1"
Logfile = "C:\Checking\test1.log"
Version = "16"
RegName = "test1Nameinfo*"
Installname = "InstallTest1"
UninstallName = "UninstallTest1"
},
$Test2 = @{
Name = "Test"
Logfile = "C:\test2.log"
Version = "7"
RegName = "test2Nameinfo*"
Installname = "InstallTest2"
UninstallName = "UninstallTest2"
},
$Test3 = @{
Name = "Test3"
Logfile = "C:\Temp\Checkhere\test3.log"
Version = "99"
RegName = "test3Nameinfo*"
Installname = "InstallTest3"
UninstallName = "UninstallTest3"
}


    $Test1Name = $Test1.name 
    $Test1Logfile = $Test1.Logfile 
    $Test1Version = $Test1.Version
    $Test1RegName = $Test1.RegName 
    $Test1Install = $Test1.InstallName 
    $Test1Uninstall = $Test1.UninstallName 

    $Test2Name = $Test2.name 
    $Test2Logfile = $Test2.Logfile 
    $Test2Version = $Test2.Version
    $Test2RegName = $Test2.RegName 
    $Test2Install = $Test2.InstallName 
    $Test2Uninstall = $Test2.UninstallName 

    $Test3Name = $Test3.name 
    $Test3Logfile = $Test3.Logfile 
    $Test3Version = $Test3.Version
    $Test3RegName = $Test3.RegName 
    $Test3Install = $Test3.InstallName 
    $Test3Uninstall = $Test3.UninstallName  

Foreach($Test in $testing){
$Key = (Get-Item "Reg").getvalue("$Test")
IF($Key -eq $null)
{
    New-Itemproperty -path "HKLM:\Software\" -value "Check" -PropertyType string -name $Test -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Write-Host "$Test created"
    $Needtocheck += $Test

}
ELSEIF($key -eq "Check")
{
    $Needtocheck += $Test
}

ELSE
{
    Write-Host "$Test already Checked"
}
}

Foreach($item in $NeedtoCheck)
{
If($item -match $Test1Name)
{
    Write-Host "$Test1Name info"
    Write-host "$Test1Name`
    $Test1Logfile`  
    $Test1Version`
    $Test1RegName` 
    $Test1Install`  
    $Test1Uninstall`
}

Else
{
    Write-Host "Not in the list"
}
}
 ....
```

Comment: not exactly sure what you are asking but `compare-object` might help with matching arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't make a lot of sense to be honest. If you want 20 checks to be setup, and then only run certain checks, then that's fine, but you really don't need additional cross checking to reference one array against another array, and redefining things like you do when you assign variables for each values in each hashtable. Personally I'd make objects not hashtables, but that's me. Actually, probably even better, make a hashtable with all available tests, then for the value make an object with the properties that you need. Oh, yeah, that'd be the way to go, but would need a little re-writing. Check this out...

```psh
$Reg = 'HKLM:\Software\'
$NeedtoCheck = @()
$testing = @('Test2','Test1','NotATest')

#Define Tests
$AllTests = @{'Test1' = [PSCustomObject]@{
Name = "Test1"
Logfile = "C:\Checking\test1.log"
Version = "16"
RegName = "test1Nameinfo*"
Installname = "InstallTest1"
UninstallName = "UninstallTest1"
}
'Test2' = [PSCustomObject]@{
Name = "Test"
Logfile = "C:\test2.log"
Version = "7"
RegName = "test2Nameinfo*"
Installname = "InstallTest2"
UninstallName = "UninstallTest2"
}
'Test3' = [PSCustomObject]@{
Name = "Test3"
Logfile = "C:\Temp\Checkhere\test3.log"
Version = "99"
RegName = "test3Nameinfo*"
Installname = "InstallTest3"
UnnstallName = "UninstallTest3"
}
}
#$allTests = @($Test1,$Test2,$Test3)

Foreach($Test in $Testing){
    If($Test -in $allTests.Keys){
        $Key = (Get-Item $Reg).getvalue($AllTests[$Test].RegName)
        Switch($Key){
            #Case - Key not there
            {[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_)}{
                New-Itemproperty -path "HKLM:\Software\" -value "Check" -PropertyType string -name $AllTests[$Test].RegName -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                Write-Host "`n$Test created"
                Write-Host "`n$Test info:"
                Write-host $allTests[$test].Name
                Write-host $allTests[$test].LogFile
                Write-host $allTests[$test].Version
                Write-host $allTests[$test].RegName
                Write-host $allTests[$test].Installname
                Write-host $allTests[$test].Uninstallname
            }
            #Case - Key = 'Check'
            {$_ -eq "Check"}{
                Write-Host "`n$Test info:`n"
                Write-host $allTests[$test].Name
                Write-host $allTests[$test].LogFile
                Write-host $allTests[$test].Version
                Write-host $allTests[$test].RegName
                Write-host $allTests[$test].Installname
                Write-host $allTests[$test].Uninstallname
            }
            #Default - Key exists and does not need to be checked
            default {
                Write-Host "`n$Test already Checked"
            }
        }
    }Else{
        Write-Host "`n$Test not in list"
    }
}
```

That should do what you were doing before, with built in responses and checks. Plus this doesn't duplicate efforts and what not. Plus it allows you to name tests whatever you want, and have all the properties you had before associated with that name. Alternatively you could add a member to each test run, like 'Status', and set that to Created, Check, or Valid, then you could filter `$AllTests` later and look for entries with a Status property, and filter against that if you needed additional reporting.

Comment: Love the idea of the status property. Very PowerShellesk

Comment: As always you came to the rescue. Honestly, I know my code didn't make much sense. I am new to this and trying to learn as much as I can from great people like you and others by asking and trying to find out better ways. Once again thank you very much for your help. @ThemadTechnician I looked here to send you a private message but couldn't find it. I would like to ask you a private question if you don't mind?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter down the tests you want to check like so, if I understand what you are asking for:

```
$Needtocheck | Where {$_ -in $testing} | 
    Foreach {... do something for NeedToCheck tests that existing in $testing ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change several pieces of the code as there were syntax errors. Guessing most were from trying to create some sample code for us to play with. I have many comments in the code but I will explain some as well outside of that.

```powershell
$Reg = "HKLM:\Software\"
$testing = "Test1","Test2", "Test3"
$allTests = @(
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Name = "Test1"
        Logfile = "C:\Checking\test1.log"
        Version = "16"
        RegName = "test1Nameinfo*"
        Installname = "InstallTest1"
        UninstallName = "UninstallTest1"
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Name = "Test2"
        Logfile = "C:\test2.log"
        Version = "7"
        RegName = "test2Nameinfo*"
        Installname = "InstallTest2"
        UninstallName = "UninstallTest2"
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Name = "Test3"
        Logfile = "C:\Temp\Checkhere\test3.log"
        Version = "99"
        RegName = "test3Nameinfo*"
        Installname = "InstallTest3"
        UninstallName = "UninstallTest3"
    }
)

$passed = $testing | ForEach-Object{
    # Changed the for construct to better allow output. Added the next line to make the rest of the code the same. 
    $test = $_
    $Key = (Get-Item $Reg).getvalue($Test)
    If($Key -eq $null){
        # New-Itemproperty creates output. Cast that to void to keep it out of $passed 
        [void](New-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\Software\" -value "Check" -PropertyType string -name $Test -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        Write-Host "$Test created"

        # Send this test to output
        Write-Output $Test
    } Elseif ($key -eq "Check")
    {
        # Send this test to output
        Write-Output $Test
    } Else {
        Write-Host "$Test already Checked"
    }
} 

$allTests | Where-Object{$passed -contains $_.Name}
```

We run all the values in `$testing` and if one is created or already "Checked" then we send it down the pipe where it populates the variable `$passed`. The we take `$allTests` and filter out every test that has a match.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thank you for your time and input. Even tho this works like a charm, I needed to display the info of each test like themadtechnician wrote it. But again, this works like a charm and I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't really do personal messages so far as I know, so I set up a chat room, find it here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77044/the-mad-techs-lab. It isn't private, people could wander in and see the conversation, but it's not tied to a specific question at least.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I think you meant this in response to your own answer.